# VNC Server Centos7 VNC client Windows 10

Tags: centos, windows, vnc

I am trying to access my Centos 7 server's desktop so I installed ...

```
[plankton@localhost ~]$ rpm -q --info tigervnc-server
Name        : tigervnc-server
Version     : 1.3.1
Release     : 4.el7_2
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Sat 09 Apr 2016 07:37:13 PM PDT
Group       : User Interface/X
Size        : 504777
License     : GPLv2+
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Thu 31 Mar 2016 01:14:19 PM PDT, Key ID 24c6a8a7f4a80eb5
Source RPM  : tigervnc-1.3.1-4.el7_2.src.rpm
Build Date  : Thu 31 Mar 2016 09:35:08 AM PDT
Build Host  : worker1.bsys.centos.org
Relocations : (not relocatable)
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
Vendor      : CentOS
URL         : http://www.tigervnc.com
Summary     : A TigerVNC server
Description :
The VNC system allows you to access the same desktop from a wide
variety of platforms.  This package includes set of utilities
which make usage of TigerVNC server more user friendly. It also
contains x0vncserver program which can export your active
X session.
```

Then I started the vncserver like so:

```
[plankton@localhost ~]$ vncserver

You will require a password to access your desktops.

Password:
Verify:
xauth:  file /home/plankton/.Xauthority does not exist

New 'localhost.localdomain:1 (plankton)' desktop is localhost.localdomain:1

Creating default startup script /home/plankton/.vnc/xstartup
Starting applications specified in /home/plankton/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/plankton/.vnc/localhost.localdomain:1.log
```

vncserver -list has this output:

```
[plankton@localhost ~]$ vncserver -list

TigerVNC server sessions:

X DISPLAY #     PROCESS ID
:1              6488
```

On my windows 10 system I install the vnc client from here: https://www.realvnc.com/download/get/1861/

when I try to connect from my windows system to my Centos 7 server I get this error.

[image]

I have disabled selinux, and execute iptables --flush as root and I am using the correct IP address.  I do not get prompted for a password.  Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oops! I needed to specify the port 5901 like so:

[image]